# How to check if I have Push permission in Git Master branch origin?

Tags: git

How to check if I have Push permission in Git Master branch origin without doing a git push ?

Comment: Git has no notion of permissions, so there is no way to answer this in the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a `--dry-run` which does everything except actually send the updates.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push